# APK file creation in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, generator, android-gradle-plugin

I tried creating an apk file in android studio, On assembling the module and then running it isn't creating any output file in the build. Only 2 folders are there in build intermediates and generated..
Any help is appreciated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually does create APK file, but not in the root project directory.
It does create it on the path project_root/module_name/build/output/apk/
Try searching for APK files in the project root directory with subdirs, and you'll find them and understand what I mean

Answer (score 0):

Yes i agree with @metalurgus Answer,
It do generates Apk file,Initially the path of generated apk is inside the project/module and you can change/specify your own the location for the apk.

[image: Choose your defined location]

After all your IDE finished generating apk,It will show an acknowledgement.

[image: Acknowledgement of generated Apk].

Click to **Show in Explorer** it will locate your apk.

Happy Coding !